# xpath how to select parent based on child

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML structure looks like this:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <E>1</E>
                <F>123</F>
            </D>

            <D>
                <E>1</E>
                <F>153</F>
            </D>
        </C>

        <C>
            <D>
                <E>1</E>
                <F>134</F>
            </D>
        </C>
    </B>

    <B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <E>2</E>
                <F>133</F>
            </D>
        </C>

        <C>
            <D>
                <E>2</E>
                <F>134</F>
            </D>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to get all "B" elements (along with its contents) where their F element has specific value, let's say 134 in this case. However, I don't want to get the other C elements along with it - so for this example I'd love to get:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <E>1</E>
                <F>134</F>
            </D>
        </C>
    </B>

    <B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <E>2</E>
                <F>134</F>
            </D>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Is this even possible? I've been playing around with xpath but the only thing I got is B element with **all** its contents (not only with the desired F element) with following xpath:
//D[F=134]/parent::C/parent::B

Thank you in advance,
Marcin

Comment: You don't really want to *select* nodes with `XPath`, you probably want to *transform* your document with `XSLT`

Comment: Well, yeah. Do you think I should just loop all of them and print the ones i need? I thought I'll select them first and then just print them, never thought of it in different way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting at the B element level (regardless of what other conditions you have on the children), you are always going to get the entire contents of the B element.

Another option could be to select at the C element level with the reverse condition (F !=  134) and remove those nodes. It would depend on your exact scenario though.